# Run an embedded CORBA naming service in Java

Tags: java, corba

Is it possible to run an *embedded naming service* with a Java 1.5 CORBA server application so that its servants can be reached via "corbaloc" short-hand URLs instead of the long IOR references, but *without* running any other daemons, like ORBD?
E.g. `corbaloc::127.0.0.1:12345/MyService`

I notice there is a `TransientNameService` class in Java 1.6+, but I'm not sure it is what I think it is..

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Sun ORB `corbaloc:` references are considered *initial references*. They do not require any naming service, and are instead resolved by the ORB itself.

Here's how to register an initial reference:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("com.sun.CORBA.POA.ORBPersistentServerPort", "12345");
ORB orb = ORB.init(args, props);
POA rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
MyServicePOA myServicePOA = new MyServiceImpl();
rootPOA.activate_object(myServicePOA);
MyService myService = myServicePOA._this(orb);

((com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB) orb).register_initial_reference("MyService", myService);
```

After this MyService will be accessible at `corbaloc::127.0.0.1:12345/MyService`